# How to Properly Uninstall Brother Twain Drivers in OS X 10.6

Tags: snow-leopard, driver, macos

I recently had a situation where I wanted to uninstall a Brother TWAIN driver and rollback to an earlier version on my MBP (OS X 10.6.8). I found [instructions](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/BSC/public/us/us_ot/en/faq/faq/000000/000300/000014/faq000314_003.html?reg=us&prod=dcp120c_us&c=us_ot&lang=en) on the Brother web site and followed them to the letter. However, I was unable to reinstall the older version (freshly downloaded from the Brother web site) - the installer provided a message indicating that a newer driver was currently installed on my system.

I ended up manually reinstalling the older driver by going into the DMG and extracting the files.

**Questions**

1. Are there any other locations that I should have looked to remove files from the newer Brother TWAIN install?
2. Are the Brother uninstall instructions complete?

Comment: They should really offer an uninstaller....

Answer (score 1):

To answer both questions at once, it seems that the Brother instructions only cover system level files.  This will not remove any files that you as a user created or installed.  I would go through the instructions again, then repeat the instructions, but for every location where it says "Macintosh HD > Library > x", I would also check at "Macintosh HD >  Users > YourUsername > Library > x".

It is also possible, depending on what version of OS (I see that you are rolling back to 10.6.8 - does that mean you were on 10.7?) that they are system installed.  I wouldn't recommend removing anything from your system folder, but it may be finding the drivers under "Macintosh HD > System > Library".